# How do I get shiny to load my data frame from my computer?

Tags: r, shiny

I have refined a large dataframe for use in a Shiny App, but I can't work out how to get Shiny to use the dataframe, my current try is below, but this fails and it can't load the plot I am expecting.

```
contVariables <- c("percent_ctax_a_c" = "Percentage of population in council tax bands A - C",
                   "percent_ctax_d_e" = "Percentage of population in council tax bands D - E",
                   "percent_ctax_f_h" = "Percentage of population in council tax bands F - H",
                   "crimes_per_10000_popn" = "Crimes (per 10'000 population)",
                   "hosp_admissions_per_100000_popn" = "Hospital Admissions (per 100'000 population)",
               "median_house_price_GBP" = "Median House Price (GBP)",
                   "mean_year_jobseekers_ages_25_49" = "Percentage of population aged 25-49 claiming Jobseekers Allowance",
                   "percent_waste_recycled" = "Percentage of waste recycled",
                   "waste_kg_per_capita" = "Waste per capita (kg)",
                   "percent_people_near_derelict" = "Percentage of    people near derelict sites")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot( {
    data("Final_Data.csv")
    p <- ggplot(data=data) +
        aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y) +
      aes_string(colour=input$Council)
    p <- p + geom_point() +
            xlab(contVariables[input$x]) + 
            ylab(contVariables[input$y])  
    p
} )    

})
```

Comment: A few issues.  'data' is a function within R, so better to name your data something else.  You need to use read.csv or read.table to read in the csv file to a data frame.  If your data set is large, better to read it in outside of shiny, save the variable as an .rds file, and then have shiny load the .rds.  It will load faster.  Then, as long as the file (rds or csv) is within the shiny app directory, it should load.

Comment: thanks Joel, fixed it using your help :)